Storing and deleting Discord UserID in a .txt file
I need to make a bot that stores the user's UserID in a txt file, and then deletes that UserID when the user does a command.
This code looks at the text file with all the users' UserID's. Then it finds the UserID of the user who did the command - and then is supposed to delete that user's UserID from the file. However, this command doesn't work - as it deletes the ENTIRETY of the text file's content - when it's only supposed to delete one line. I have browsed for an hour in forums to solve this: but nothing has worked.
@client.command()
async def unreserve(ctx):
    author = (ctx.author.id)

    with open('ReservedUsers.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open('ReservedUsers.txt', 'w') as f:
        for line in lines:
            if line == author:
                f.write(line)

And this is an example of the 'ReservedUsers.txt' file:
000000000000000001
000000000000000002
000000000000000003


Your current code would remove all the other IDs and keep to one you actually want to remove. It is not working because there is a \n at the end of each row, but you do not take that into consideration in your if statement
UPDATE:
It is also a problem, that ctx.author.id is an int, so in the compare it must be converted into string.
@client.command()
async def unreserve(ctx):
    author = (ctx.author.id)
    with open(f"ReservedUsers.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open(f"ReservedUsers.txt", "w") as f:
        for line in lines:
            if line.strip("\n") != str(author):
                f.write(line)


Sadly it doesn't. No error logs or anything, either. The command just doesn't do anything in the text file. No changes.

The meanwhile I edited the answer, check it again please :)

Still the same result

Could you please print out the author after the assignment and share that with me?

It prints out my UserID: 909539730553708593

It works for me. If the content of ReservedUsers.txt identical with the one you presented it should not apply any change. If you change the author in the code to 000000000000000002 then it should remove that one line from the txt. Can you check this?

Yep, my UserID is in the text file. I used the fake one for demonstration purposes. It still does not work, unfortunately.

I modifed the code again, lets see if it solves the problem.
